# Replacing NaNs in DataFrame not working due to non-float NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to write a DataFrame to an Excel file using xlsxwriter and am having some issues with NaN values not being filled properly.

Regardless of whether I use `df.fillna`, `df.replace` or the `na_rep` option on the writer, a few columns retain any NaN values in the DataFrame.

Investigating using `pdb.set_trace()`, I found the following:

```
(Pdb) df['col_name'][0]
Decimal('NaN')
(Pdb) Decimal(np.nan)
Decimal('NaN')
(Pdb) df['col_name'][0]==Decimal(np.nan)
False
(Pdb) na=df['col_name'][0]
(Pdb) na
Decimal('NaN')
(Pdb) na==df['col_name'][0]
False
(Pdb) df['col_name'][0]
Decimal('NaN')
```

How can I identify these values to replace them if I can't define them?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are using `decimal.Decimal` types instead of standard `float` ?

Comment: The data filling the DataFrame is pulled from a Django project, and the field relating to the column in question is a Decimal field.

Comment: got it. I provided a solution below which should deal with the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Decimal` format is not important to you, you can recast as `float`.

If `Decimal` format *is* important to you, then `pandas` isn't the ideal choice since it is not vectorizable like `numpy` arrays.

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
from decimal import Decimal

s = pd.Series([Decimal(np.nan), Decimal(5.1)])

test = s.isnull().tolist()  # [False, False]

s = s.astype(float)

test = s.isnull().tolist()  # [True, False]
```

Answer (score 1):

[You cannot use `==` to check for `NaN`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565164/what-is-the-rationale-for-all-comparisons-returning-false-for-ieee754-nan-values). You should use `np.isnan()`.

Comment: `np.isnan` won't accept the value as an input type, but using `pd.isnull` returns `False`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the following function:

```
def pandas_replace_decimal_by_value(df, column, value):
    idx = df[column].apply(math.isnan)
    df.loc[idx, column] = value
```